# In Conquest mode, how fast does a team "bleed" Tickets when they own less than half the bases?

Tags: battlefield-3

In the description for the Battlefield 3 mode Conquest, it's noted that when either team has less than half of the bases in their possession, they will "bleed", or lose, Tickets over time. How quickly does this happen? Does it occur at a set rate? If there are five bases and all five are captured, will the losing team lose Tickets faster than in a situation where four bases are captured?

Comment: Have you ever played a ticket-based CP game?  Dominion in LoL, Arathi Basin in WoW...

Comment: @NickT No, never. Why?

Comment: Works pretty much the exact same way.

Comment: I'll do some testing to figure out exact times, but it works based on the amount of bases held. A team will bleed a lot quicker if the other team has 5 points as opposed to 3 points.

Answer (score 1):

You have to own more than half the points for bleeding to occur. There are usually (always?) an odd number of points, so 2/3 or 3/5 is required for bleeding of tickets.

At max "bleed" -- when the enemy owns *all* capture points -- based on my testing, you lose **about 1 ticket every 3 or 4 seconds.** It definitely hurts and frequently causes us to lose matches where the ticket count is close. It's also why I get frustrated with teams where they're more interested in fighting than making sure we don't lose all the damn capture points, but I digress..

I can't say exactly how many tickets you bleed when the enemy owns more than half but not quite all the capture points. It's less rapid, but I'll have to do a bit more testing.

Comment: The rage is all too frequent. Caps, not kills.